# tampermonkey best practices for sharing

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have developed a userscript for blind users that reads screen on a card-game website playing audio files and also lets user play cards using keyboard instead of mouse.

The script is now working fine on my computer but I plan on keep updating it with new features.

Initially this was designed for just 1 person, but word spread and more people from other countries are gonna use it.

My question is this: what is the recomended way to export the script into their computers? Is there any kind of "userscript store" for tampermonkey scripts where I can place the script for anyone to download and use?

I have seen tutorials explaining how to download scripts other made, but none about sharing the ones you make with others.

How are new versions managed?

I was thinking about copying the main code into my personal website and reference it as a required script so anytime I update it they get a new version, but wonder if this is the way to go.

Comment: ⚠ Tampermonkey is not open source since long, it's basically a closes source of violentmonkey, which is open source and much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can host tampermonkey scripts on [Greasyfork](https://greasyfork.org/en). You can either [upload code directly](https://greasyfork.org/en/script_versions/new) or [link to a file in a GitHub repository](https://greasyfork.org/en/import), which can be set to auto-update.

There are many other ways/places to host tampermonky scripts, this is just what I've used recently. [You can read about the other ways, here.](https://www.tampermonkey.net/scripts.php?ext=dhdg)

Comment: Thanks, my code starts with a lot of

`const LEFT_KEY = KeyEvent.DOM_VK_LEFT || 37;`

So that user can edit the key shortcuts, but if they update, any edit will be reset, is there any practical workaround?

Comment: The [Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey get/setValue functions](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setValue) might be what you're looking for. You might need to add the line `@grant GM_setValue` to use this feature, I have not tested. ([Read more about `grant`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_grant))